# Is it necessary to install Groovy for Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle. I see that Gradle lib already has a file 'groovy-all-2.4.12.jar' in lib folder and I don't seem to have any issues with tasks and or dependencies. Still, is it necessary in any scenario to install Groovy on my system on top of it?

Reason why I ask is that, when I do 'gradle -v' in command prompt, I see few warnings. Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With gradle it is strongly recommended to use the Gradle wrapper committed into the project you are building instead of a system-wide gradle distribution (that is `gradlew` and not `gralde`). This guarantees the matching version of Gradle your project has been tested with.

With the Gradle wrapper you do not need to care about any dependencies that Grade itself needs, such as groovy and you really do not need to install anything of Gradle at all as the wrapper in your project will download all it needs on the first run.

The minimum setup for the Gradle wrapper is:

```
/gradlew - unix shell script
/gradlew.bat - windows batch script
/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties -- the properties file defining the version
/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar -- the minimal jar (50Kb) that takes care about the rest
```

The above files must be committed into your project and this is what 99% of all gradle projects do. You will find further details here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html